# Bootstrap Navbar disappears on mobile after using it once

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, navbar, mobile-development

I have an issue with my Bootstrap Navbar. When I use the navbar on a mobile device, it disappears after the toggledown.

Here is my code for the navbar:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!--Navbar-->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top" id="navbarSupportedContent">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Ewert Loitz Personenberförderung</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="true" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Startseite <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#ÜberUns">Über uns</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#Fuhrpark">Fuhrpark</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Kontakt</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Karriere</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

[image: Missing Navbar]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outer `<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top" id="navbarSupportedContent">` and the inner `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">` share the same id `navbarSupportedContent`. (In fact, elements with the same id are not allowed in HTML.)

All the elements with the id `navbarSupportedContent` are collasped accodring to the `data-toggle`
and `data-target` attributes defined in the `<button>` after clicking the it, including `nav#navbarSupportedContent`, so the whole navbar disappers.

All you need to do is to remove `id="navbarSupportedContent"` from the `<nav>` element.

Ref: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/navbar/#supported-content